# "token eof expected" error in power query

Tags: token, powerquery, eof

I have a bunch of production values and my goal is to sort out the hourly production, for that I need to substract values in different rows but in the same column

| Hour | Machine | Production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 10303 | 3 |
| 00:00 | 10305 | 16 |
| 00:00 | 10308 | 1 |
| 00:00 | 10500 | 134 |
| 01:00 | 10303 | 3 |
| 01:00 | 10305 | 18 |
| 01:00 | 10308 | 3 |
| 01:00 | 10500 | 134 |

basically I want to substract production value of machine 10303 at 1am and value at 0am, then 2am minus 1am, etc... and this for all 4 machines

I have this code that I put in power query's advanced editor but it keeps saying "token eof expected", can someone spot what I missed ? (it says the error is on the comma just above `#"Expanded Difference"`)

```
`#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Previous step", {"Machine"}, {
    {"Difference", (t) => Table.AddColumn(t, "Difference", each 
        if t[Production]{4} - t[Production]{1} < 0 then null 
        else if t[Valeur]{4} - t[Valeur]{1} >= 0 then t[Valeur]{4} - t[Valeur]{1}
        else null,
        Decimal.Type)
    }
}),
#"Expanded Difference" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Difference", 
    {"Production", "Difference"})
in
    #"Expanded Difference"`
```

Comment: I almost edited it away, but the code does not error if you dont have the ' character before the '#"Group and the ' character after the Difference"'

Answer (score 0):

Does this help in powerquery with your overall goal?

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Machine"}, {{"data", each 
     let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Diff", each try [Production] - #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Production] otherwise null),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom","To", each Text.From(#"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Hour])&" - "&Text.From([Hour]) ),
    #"Trim"=Table.RemoveFirstN( #"Added Custom2",1)
    in #"Trim"
   , type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Diff", "To"}, {"Diff", "TimeSlot"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]